# Overflow for filling listbox with For Each

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, overflow

I have created communication tool with Excel for the production floor the engineering, programmers and work prep. Its been working properly for a while, but now I got a Error 6 Overflow.

This communication tool uses 3 different Excels, one that production uses to send in feedback, one that collects all the data and then one that is used as portal to look into the feedback and sign off feedback when its been implemented.

I have tried several things like putting Exit For and Lastrow in the Range, but then it doesn't fill the Listbox anymore.

The code that has been working for a while, and still works btw for other departments with more rows.

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 Dim myData As Workbook 
 Set myData = Workbooks.Open("R:\Production\Productieleiding\Nietverplaatsen!\Terugkoppeling productie.xlsm") 
 Sheets("Archief").Select 
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel2").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

 Dim LastRow As Long LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
 Range("B2:H" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Range("C2:C" & LastRow), _    
 order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes


Dim cMatrijs As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet Set ws = Worksheets("Archief")

'the line below is the loop where the overflow occurs!!!    

For Each cMatrijs In ws.Range("MatrijsLists2")
  With Me.ListBox
      .AddItem cMatrijs.Value
       .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cMatrijs.Offset(0, 1).Value

   End With
 Next cMatrijs


  Me.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsBoth 
  Me.ScrollHeight = Me.InsideHeight *1.1 
  'Me.ScrollWidth = Me.InsideWidth * 2 
   myData.Close

   End Sub
```

Comment: how many items do you put in your listbox?

Comment: It puts 205 rows in it now. For another departments it fills it with 400+, so I dont see why that should be a problem?

Comment: Which line errors out exactly?

Comment: It overflows on the `for each` line. I will edit this in the original post